# .net test explorer just run one of many test projects i have in solution file in vscode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, test-explorer

I have a solution file with many test projects. I use vscode so i install the .net test explorer extension. The extension find all my tests in the explorer but when i try to run, just the test in of one test project in solution show results, the other tests runs but with no results. What i supposed to do?

I already tried to update the projects in the solution, create a new project and add to the solution.
What i discovered is that when i delete the project which the tests are showing results, another projetc in the solution start to showing tests results, but just one project

Comment: related: https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-dotnet-test-explorer/issues you can check and see if this is a known issue.

Comment: yep, i found my problem in this page https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-dotnet-test-explorer/issues/367. Thank you!